# sqlSave pads numeric/integer with space

Tags: r, rodbc

I have some data which I am trying to upload to a table in a database. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Fred", "George", "David"), data = c(10, 100, 1000))
```

When I am using the `RODBC::sqlSave` function (with `fast = FALSE` to insert one row at a time) however, it is padding the numeric or integer values with spaces. So in the database, the entries under the `data` column will be `"  10", " 100", "1000"`. So for example, if I were to upload the above dataframe and then query that data using the following

```
tmp = RODBC::sqlQuery(ch, query = "SELECT * FROM My_Tbl")
```

then then output will look something like this:

```
> str(tmp)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
$ name : chr "Fred" "George" "David"
$ data : chr "  10" " 100" "1000"
```

The database data type for the `data` column is of type `varchar(10)` as the data sometimes have a leading letter. In the case I am working with however, there are only numbers involved.

My question is why is the `sqlSave` function padding the numeric data and is there anything I can do to stop it from doing so?

NOTE: I know it is the `sqlSave` function causing the issue because when I use `verbose = TRUE`, I can see the output of the `INSERT` statements and the indeed have padded data. Also, this is made up data for the purposes of an example.

Answer (score 1):

From the help of sqlSave:

> If fast = FALSE all data are sent as character strings. If fast =
>   TRUE, integer and double vectors are sent as types SQL_C_SLONG and
>   SQL_C_DOUBLE respectively.

So try it without the `fast=FALSE` option. You could also try the `typeInfo` option.

Comment: I have to use `fast = FALSE` unfortunately as I am using SQL Server 2005 (I can't change this) and `fast = TRUE` uses SQL Server 2008 and onwards syntax which makes R crash for me.